# SQL - Row sum with condition from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum, case

I have 2 tables and want to get the row sum from 2 tables with conditions.
Here are my tables:

[tabale1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ejxo.png),
[tabale2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15FQk.png)

i want the row sum from 2 tables, like:

```
if sk not null sum sk but if it is null sk = ss
```

For example, the total sum of sh2 is: 19 + 5 + 11 + 5 = 40

I really need that, please help!

Table1:
[image: table1]

Table2:
[image: table2]

Comment: Please just show some more details

Comment: @vol7ron its fix now

Comment: @AbdullahDibas its fix now srry my frist time ask anythings here

Comment: What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: @vol7ron ok i want the result to be like this
for example   sh2 :
19 + 5 + 11 + 5 = 40 
for each name calculate them all in a table

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh   microsoft sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next sql will return the sum over the tables, grouping by name:

```
select name, sum(total) total from 
(select name, sum(coalesce(sk,ss)) total
 from table1
 group by name
 union all
 select name, sum(coalesce(sk,ss)) total
 from table2
 group by name
) t
group by name
```

The clause "group by" inside of the subqueries is very important because whether the tables return a lot of lines, they will reduce the number of lines for the "group by" on the query, optimizing time and using less memory.

Comment: You'd better do `UNION ALL` instead. (In case table1 and table2 have the same sum for a name.)

Comment: Yes, because the intrinsic distinct in "UNION", thanks. Fixed.

Comment: @rafaedez hi and tnx one more thing how can do it with select case ?

Comment: Those group by clauses in the derived table may be important for some products, but completely redundant for other products. And OP has not specified dbms here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `coalesce` to pick sk if sk is not null. Otherwise (if sk is null), ss will be used.

`UNION ALL` the two tables, and `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select name, sum(skss)
from 
(
    select name, coalesce(sk, ss) skss
    from table1
    union all
    select name, coalesce(sk, ss) skss
    from table2
) dt
group by name
```