# sql coalesce chenge to select case

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, case

I have 2 tables and want to get the row sum from 2 tables with conditions
the result to be like this for example sh2 : 19 + 5 + 11 + 5 = 40 for each name calculate them all in a table
i use that code

```
select name, sum(total) total from 
(select name, sum(coalesce(sk,ss)) total
 from table1
 group by name
 union all
 select name, sum(coalesce(sk,ss)) total
 from table2
 group by name
) t
group by name
```

but i want use select and case for that code

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: @jarlh hi you help me one time tnx for that here is sample data
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162761/sql-row-sum-with-condition-from-2-tables/43166625#43166625

Answer (score 0):

```
select name,SUM(total)total from(
      select name,sum(case when sk>0 then sk else ss end )total from majale group by name
      union all
      select name,sum(case when sk>0 then sk else ss end )from ketab group by name
      union all
      select name,sum(case when sk>0 then sk else ss end )from savabegh group by name
      )t
      group by name
```